# Bootstrap 5 large devices getting bottom white space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 and There's always a large device to bottom showing white space .Please look at the attached image, dose any onw know solutions?  and why the  getting this white space? any reason?

[image: Image description here]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.84.0">
    <title>Pricing example · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="pricing.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <title>Check</title>
    <path d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="container py-3">
  <header>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="32" class="me-2" viewBox="0 0 118 94" role="img"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
        <span class="fs-4">Pricing example</span>
      </a>

      <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Enterprise</a>
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Support</a>
        <a class="py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4 fw-normal">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="fs-5 text-muted">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm border-primary">
          <div class="card-header py-3 text-white bg-primary border-primary">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  

    
  </main>


</div>


    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the content to expand and fill all available space, it is all about nesting flexbox containers and designating which child will expand with `.flex-grow-1`.
For such a layout:

- Make sure the content is at least the size of the viewport make the `.container` also be a `.min-vh-100`
- Both `.container` and `main` need to be a `.d-flex.flex-column`.
- `main` and `.row` both need to be a `.flex-grow-1`.
- The `.card`s need to be `.h-100` to fill the height of the `.row`.
- Move the `button`s inside of a `.card-footer` to have them align with each other across the row.
- To preserve some vertical spacing between the `.cards` when stacked, make the `.row` a `.g-3`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->


<style>
  .bd-placeholder-img {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
    }
  }
</style>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <title>Check</title>
        <path d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
      </symbol>
    </svg>

<div class="container py-3 min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <header>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="32" class="me-2" viewBox="0 0 118 94" role="img">
              <title>Bootstrap</title>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            </svg>
        <span class="fs-4">Pricing example</span>
      </a>

      <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Enterprise</a>
        <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Support</a>
        <a class="py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4 fw-normal">Pricing</h1>
      <p class="fs-5 text-muted">
        Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-3 mb-3 text-center flex-grow-1">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm h-100">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm h-100">
          <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm border-primary h-100">
          <div class="card-header py-3 text-white bg-primary border-primary">
            <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This white space appears because there's just nothing to put there.** If you want to fill it, you may arrange the cards in a vertical stack (Bootstrap class `.vstack`, [learn more about Bootstrap stacks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/stacks/)), not in a row.

There's an issue: if you use the Bootstrap classes `.gap-*` (that define the gap between stacked blocks), you won't solve your problem because they calculate gaps using `rem` (depends on the font size of `html` element, but doesn't depend on the screen height — and the solution assumes sensitivity to the height of the screen). The only solution I see is to define your own class called e.g. `.gap-big` that uses `vh` to calculate the gap. `vh` is a way to solve your problem because it means *percents of the screen height* — the bigger your screen, the bigger my gap. White space in the bottom will be smaller.

If it's still too big, you may replace `gap: 10vh !important;` in the below snippet with a bigger value (e.g. `gap: 15vh !important;`).

The solution I suggest is below — run the snippet and click "Full page".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.84.0">
    <title>Pricing example · Bootstrap v5.0</title>
 
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
      
      .gap-big {
        gap: 10vh !important;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="pricing.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <title>Check</title>
        <path d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>

      <div class="container py-3">
        <header>
          <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="32" class="me-2" viewBox="0 0 118 94" role="img"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
              <span class="fs-4">Pricing example</span>
            </a>

            <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
              <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Features</a>
              <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Enterprise</a>
              <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Support</a>
              <a class="py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4 fw-normal">Pricing</h1>
            <p class="fs-5 text-muted">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this Bootstrap example. It’s built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little customization.</p>
          </div>
        </header>

        <main>
          <div class="vstack gap-big text-center">
            <div>
              <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Free</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>10 users included</li>
                  <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Pro</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>20 users included</li>
                  <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Priority email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get started</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm border-primary">
              <div class="card-header py-3 text-white bg-primary border-primary">
                <h4 class="my-0 fw-normal">Enterprise</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29<small class="text-muted fw-light">/mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>30 users included</li>
                  <li>15 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Phone and email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Contact us</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are wrapping everything in col so it has defined margin and padding and other classes too are having padding which are creating huge space

Comment: So what is your solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the ul mt-3 mb-4 is making extra space as mb is margin bottom

Comment: Don't you think the asker needs a *solution*?